# Maintaining session among stateless services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am planning to build set of stateless REST services and maintain session information within DynamoDB for the sake of scalability at service layer. Does this approach make sense?

Thanks.

Meks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, Amazon has official support for this. Take a look here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-tomcat-session-manager.html